# DropDownList on mvc filters a display of cards/boxes, but I can't display all the cards on load or with default selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Partial View that can currently display three cards/boxes that contain snippets of information about different case studies. I want this page to on load, display all the cards, but then also have a dropdown menu that filters each card by their CaseStudyIndustry property and be able to go back to displaying all the cards when you select "Select an industry"/the default selection.

I got a lot of help from http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2011/06/filter-and-display-data-with-aspnet-mvc-part-2partial-views-and-jquery.html, but I can't seem to get all the cards to display onload or when selecting the default DropDownList item. I've been stuck on this for a few weeks.

Here is my code:

Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<KenCast.Models.CaseStudies>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_CaseStudyCard.cshtml", item);
}
```

Index/page with the dropdown menu:

```
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<fieldset>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Industries", "Select an industry")
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="target">
    </div>
    <div id="log">
    </div>
</fieldset>
<h3>For development only</h3>
<p>This link below to create new application is for development only. Will change once Identity is added to this app.</p>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
```

Script from: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2011/06/filter-and-display-data-with-aspnet-mvc-part-2partial-views-and-jquery.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Industries").change(function () {
        $("#log").ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
            alert(exception);
        });
        // loads all cards from all industries
        // Changes cards by industry when selected from dropdown menu
        var industrySelected = $("select option:selected").text();
        $.get('@Url.Action("CaseStudiesByIndustryPartial")', { id: industrySelected }, function (data) {
            $("#target").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var industries = new SelectList(_context.CaseStudies.Select(c => c.CaseStudyIndustry).Distinct().ToList());
    ViewBag.Industries = industries;
    return View();
}

public PartialViewResult CaseStudiesByIndustryPartial(string id)
{
    return PartialView(
        _context.CaseStudies.Where(c => c.CaseStudyIndustry == id).OrderBy(c => c.CaseStudyDate)
            .ThenBy(c => c.CaseStudyTitle).ToList());    
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: The value of `id` in the `CaseStudiesByIndustryPartial()` method will be `null` if you select the first option, so you need to test that (and only include the `.Where()` if its not `null`.

Comment: And to load it initially use `@{ Html.RenderAction("CaseStudiesByIndustryPartial"); }` in the main view

Comment: I added an if statement to the controller for when the value of the id equals the default text. It worked! When I select the default selection after choosing another item in the DropDownList,  it displays the cards. YAY! :) Thank you @StephenMuecke

Comment: The problem still remains about getting the cards to initially load. When I insert the suggestion above, I get this error: 'HtmlHelper<IEnumberable<CaseStudies>>' does not contain a definition for 'RenderAction' and no extension method 'RenderAction' and no extension method 'RenderAction' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper<IEnumerable<CaseStudies>>' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? '  I've been googling all afternoon and still haven't figured out a solution. Any helpful hints, @StephenMuecke? Thanks!

Comment: Have just noticed the your code is for asp.net-core-mvc - you need to tag the question correctly :). In mvc-core, you need to use view components (`Html.RenderAction()` is not supported)

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke! That worked!!!! It took me awhile to figure out how to use the view components, but it is now working properly. Thank you a bazillion. It was getting really frustrating!

Comment: You might want to adding your own answer with what worked for you and accept it to close this out (along the accepting answers on your other questions that have been solved such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240976/getting-an-image-to-appear-on-a-popup-window-with-angular-js))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out with the hints from Stephen Muecke. The value of the first item selected in the dropbox was "Select an industry", so I used an if statement to change the displayed cards when "Select an industry was selected.

Code within the Controller now looks like this:

```
 //Responsible for filtering case studies when item in DropDownList is selected. 
    public PartialViewResult CaseStudiesByIndustryPartial(string id)
    {
        if (id == "Select an industry") return PartialView(
            _context.CaseStudies.OrderByDescending(c => c.CaseStudyDate)
                .ThenBy(c => c.CaseStudyTitle).ToList());

        else return PartialView(
            _context.CaseStudies.Where(c => c.CaseStudyIndustry == id).OrderByDescending(c => c.CaseStudyDate)
                 .ThenBy(c => c.CaseStudyTitle).ToList());
    }
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant way to do this, but it works! If anyone has another suggestion for how to write this without repeating code, please let me know!

The code in the controller, changed the cards in the view, but would only display all of the cards after I had selected another industry and then selected "Select an industry".

I ended up creating a ViewComponent that loaded all of the cards when the page loaded. The ViewComponent  ended up looking like this:

```
  namespace KenCast.ViewComponents
{
    public class CaseStudiesViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        //allows for data access
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CaseStudiesViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext c)
    {
        _context = c;
    }

    public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var casestudies = (from cs in _context.CaseStudies.ToList()
                          .OrderByDescending(cs => cs.CaseStudyDate)
                          .ThenBy(cs => cs.CaseStudyTitle)
                           select cs).ToList();

        return Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View(casestudies));
    }

}
```

}

I called the ViewComponent in the index page (page with the dropdown menu). The index page now looks like this:

```
 <h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<fieldset>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Industries", "Select an industry")
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="target"> @* Loads data from CaseStudiesViewComponent *@
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("CaseStudies")
    </div>
    <div id="log">
    </div>
</fieldset>

<h3>For development only</h3>
<p>This link below to create new application is for development only. Will change once Identity is added to this app.</p>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

@* Script from: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2011/06/filter-and-display-data-with-aspnet-mvc-part-2partial-views-and-jquery.html *@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Industries").change(function () {
            $("#log").ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                alert(exception);
            });
            //loads all cards from all industries
            //Changes cards by industry when selected from dropdown menu
            var industrySelected = $("select option:selected").text();
            $.get('@Url.Action("CaseStudiesByIndustryPartial")',
                  { id: industrySelected }, function (data) {
                      $("#target").html(data);
                  });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps if anyone else runs into a similar issue.